# FAKE error when trying to use Fake.FscHelper

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I'm trying to use FAKE to build my F# project.
The `build.fsx` looks like below and works fine.

```
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open Fake

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
    trace "Hello World from FAKE"
)

RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

Then I want to use fsc from FAKE. Following the official tutorial, I added one line `open Fake.FscHelper` and get below error message:

```
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open Fake
open Fake.FscHelper

// this value is not a function and can not be applied
// union case FscParam.Target: TargetType -> FscParam
Target "Default" (fun _ ->
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    trace "Hello World from FAKE"
)

RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

I appreciate if anyone can give me any advice.

I'm using VS Code on Mac with Mono 4.2.1.

And my `paket.lock` looks like below:

```
NUGET
  remote: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
  specs:
    FAKE (4.21.0)
    FSharp.Core (4.0.0.1)
    FsUnit (2.0.0)
      FSharp.Core (>= 3.1.2.5)
      NUnit (3.0.1)
    NUnit (3.0.1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the module `FscHelper` defines a constructor called `Target` ([see source](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/c544eb7a4a567a91ff0c9f05dab1b2d00458b54e/src/app/FakeLib/FscHelper.fs#L244)), and that constructor conflicts with the `Target` function from the `TargetHelper` module. There is an [issue filed about it](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1155).

Until the issue is fixed, there are three ways to work around this ambiguity:

1. Don't open `FscHelper`, just use all its innards in a qualified manner (e.g. `FscHelper.Compile` etc.)
2. Re-alias the `TargetHelper.Target` function in the local scope:

   ```
   open Fake
   open Fake.FscHelper

   let Target = TargetHelper.Target

   Target "Default" (fun _ ->
       trace "Hello World from FAKE"
   )
   ```
3. Reorder the `open` statements:

   ```
   open Fake.FscHelper
   open Fake
   ```

And since you're using this helper, note that the [documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/fsc.html) for it is [outdated](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1156). In particular, the `Fsc` task is deprecated in favor of the `Compile` task ([see source](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/FscHelper.fs#L520)).

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of the open statements

```
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake.FscHelper
open Fake

Target "a" (fun _ -> 
  ["a.fs"] |> Compile []
```

The order of your open statements determines the precedence of the name resolution with the later opened modules and namespaces taking precedent.